# Impredicativity example in HOL

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

From [these notes](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/MPRI/2-7-1/notes.pdf) pages 37-38. In HOL, I'm giving the task of proving:

$\vdash \forall x^T. \forall y^T. (=_T x^T y^T) \implies (=_T y^T x^T)$

applying forall and implication introduction and the definition of $=_T$ I get:

$(\forall_{T \to O} \lambda P'^{T \to O}. P' x^T \implies P' y^T), P y^T \vdash P x^T$

Here I set $P' = \lambda z^T. (=_o (P z^T)  (P x^T))$ and according to forall elimination we can prove: $P' x^T \implies P' y^T \equiv (=_o (P x^T) (P x^T)) \implies (=_o (P y^T) (P x^T))$ since I know that $=_o (P x^T) (P x^T)$ holds I have derived $=_o (P y^T) (P x^T)$ and then taking $P'' = id$ in the definition of equality we derive $P y^T \implies P x^T$.

From the text,

> These two last exercises are a little trickier:  they are solved by instantiating the predicate variable by a property involving equality itself.  They therefore highlight the  feature  of  HOL  known  as impredicativity:   we  can  define  a  new  proposition(resp.  property) by quantifying over all propositions (resp.  properties); that is the quantification includes the object which is being defined by the quantification.

I don't see what they mean here. Here we are not defining anything. We are proving something. So I guess the phrase should be:

> we can prove a new property by quantifying over all properties that is the quantification includes the property which is being proved by the quantification.

Ok, then it is true that above quantification is ranging over any property. However, I didn't make use of the particular property I wanted to prove. Or did I? My instantiation "includes" the property I want to prove... Is that what they mean?

Comment: I think they simply mean that $P$ was *instantiated* with a predicate involving equality, but they said "defined" because an instantiation feels like a "temporary definition". Even you yourself wrote "here I set $P = \cdots$ and according to ...", which can certainly be read as if you were defining $P$.